# Advice regarding Google Webmaster 404 errors

Tags: seo, http-status-code-404, google-search-console

I created a CMS for a website and integrated Google Analytics. The site changes it's content every week (adding, editing, removing pages and URLs)  and I rewrite the sitemap every time when one of this actions occurred.

The problem is that the web crawlers from Google detect a lot of 404 error pages.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Getting reports about 404s is perfectly normal and generally no need to worry about them. 
Check where does Google find those 404 URLs, you can see that in Search Console (formerly Webmaster Tools), and see if you can fix them. If you cannot, if you have great content, sooner or later you'll get better links.

What you could do additionally, is to create custom 404 pages, where you link to content on your site that's similar to the missing page (if it's possible to determine that), or that's popular on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you feel that the page is for content that won't be coming back on the site. you can remove the URL for their index by using the remove URL option.